# How to update my notification to show my time counter changing?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-notifications

I am almost finished with this toy app game I am making.

**Problem:** 
My notification is always showing my counter to be 30000. Why isn't it timing down?

**What I have done:** 
I have implemented a simple Service class and a custom timer to tick down. Eventually once I am sure the timer is working I will exit the entire game.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.redshirtmarblez;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TimingService extends Service{

    public long counter = 30000;
    private Context ctx;
    private Activity localActivity;


    private NotificationManager nm;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
          super.onCreate();
          nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          declareNotification();
          timer.start();
          //Toast.makeText(this, "Timer is :" + counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //showNotification();
    }


    public void getActivity(Activity activity)
    {
        localActivity = activity;
    }

    //count to end the game
    public CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000){

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
            counter = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
        }

        public void onFinish(){
             counter = 0;


 //Kill the game 
             int i = android.os.Process.myPid();
             android.os.Process.killProcess(i);

        }

    };

    /*
     * Show a notification while this service is running 
     */
    public void declareNotification()
    {
        //Declare a new notification 
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "A New Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimingService.class);
        PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "herp", "counter: " + counter, activity);


  //This is clearly not 1337, but a good joke
            startForeground(1337, notification);

    }

}
```

All this does when it runs is shows "A New Notification", and then changes to "herp counter: 30000". However, this notification never changes. It just stays 30000. Why? I thought I fixed this with making the flag ongoing?

Comment: Don't do this -> `android.os.Process.killProcess(i);` it is really bad practice in `Android`. Also `0` isn't a valid value for the `flags` parameter of `PendingIntent.getActivity(...)`

Comment: Thanks. The only reason I did that is because when I use activity.finish(), the application gives me an error saying it doesn't know why the app shutdown. I know there are tons of reasons not to do this in general. This is just a toyapp and I am playing around with ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`counter` is not a reference; the notification will not update with its new value until you explicitly tell it to.

Have a look at [the documentation on updating an existing notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating). Your ID is `1337` here, so you can use that to update it.

In fact, you may just be able to call `declareNotification()` again from your `onTick()` method... If this doesn't work, however, I would suggest keeping a reference to the [`Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) object (as a member variable), then updating it, and use [`nm.notify(1337, /* your notification object */);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. I just decided to learn how to use Notifications. I only give two. One tells the user that the game is on a timer. It updates once right before it closes.

Answer (score 22):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setUsesChronometer(boolean)

> Show the when field as a stopwatch. Instead of presenting when as a
>   timestamp, the notification will show an automatically updating
>   display of the minutes and seconds since when. Useful when showing an
>   elapsed time (like an ongoing phone call). The counter can also be set
>   to count down to when when using setChronometerCountDown(boolean).

No updating required, works off the `setWhen()` value

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_default_notification)
        .setTicker("Ticker Text")  
        .setWhen(when)  // the time stamp, you will probably use System.currentTimeMillis() for most scenarios
        .setUsesChronometer(true)
        .setContentTitle("Title Text")
        .setContentText("Content Text");
```

Comment: is it possible to show the time stamp in the **notification title** in this way? I don't have a good feeling about updating it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to use a notification. But you need to keep updating your notification. For a simple fix add

```
declareNotification();
```

underneath this line:

```
counter = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
```

Note that this isn't a great way to code it. Really you should pass a method only updating the notification rather than "creating" a new one. However as long as they have the same ID, one will replace the other. 
Also just to use a more up to date way of managing notifications, use

```
NotificationCompat.builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
```